# Minimum Google Chrome and Microsoft Edge Version for stable running ASP.NET MVC, Vue.js application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, version, microsoft-edge

We use latest ASP.NET MVC, Vue.js at company. Is there a version for chrome and Microsoft edge that you can say that it should be above the following version in order not to update all computers?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, it looks like you are using the Vue.JS as a frontend of your application.

I try to find it but did not get any list that shows the minimum version browser support for Vue.js. (Reference: [Browser Compatibility](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/browser-compatibility.html#browser-compatibility))

For unsupported JS code, you can try to use polyfills.

If we talk about ASP.NET MVC then it is a serverside technology.

With MVC, you have full control of the generated HTML, so you can create your own markup, javascript, and CSS to support the Edge, Chrome browsers.

In general scenario, if you are using the latest version of the .Net MVC, Vue-JS, Chrome/Edge browsers then you should not have any issues. Further, it depends on specific things in your projects that might create some issues with the older versions of the Chrome/Edge browsers.